# What unit of measurement is Titanium Mobiles "font-size"?

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

Trying to find what unit of measurement Titanium uses for defining the font size in mobile applications. Want to match it up to Photoshop for mockup purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its in pixels, but don't forget your photoshop mockups need to be double the size for the retina display.

So your mockup would be font-size 24px and in Titanium you would specify 12px.

Comment: Are you sure the px don't get converted to points when the js is turned into the objective C symbols by Titanium? Good point on the retina display btw!

Comment: I disagree, font-size:1em works best - EM works best for fluid regardless of retina hype.

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, font sizes are in typographical points (1/72 of an inch), so font size 12 should be the same visual size on both devices. (Of course, it will be larger in the Retina simulator, because it's twice as many pixels.)

Note that other iOS sizes are in Apple "points," which don't correspond to typographic points. An Apple "point" is 1px on a pre-Retina device, and 2px on a Retina device.

On Android, you can specify units. The default is pixels (for example, 12 and '12px' both specify 12 pixels). You can also specify sizes in Android's density-independent pixels, points, millimeters or inches. So:

- '12dp' == 12 DIP (roughly equivalent to Apple's "points")
- '12pt' == 12 points  (typographical points)
- '12mm' == 12 millimeters
- '12in' is a REALLY big font

On a medium-density device like the G1, 12px == 12dp. On a high-density device (most of the newer Android phones with 800x480, 854x480, or 960x540 screens), 12dp renders twice as big as 12px--just like the Apple "point" system.

Why aren't DIP the default unit on Android? That I can't answer. I guess Androids just like pixels.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/7092024#7092024) it's pixels converted to points. According the actual [Apple UIKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html) it's points as well but I'm not sure if Appcelerator changed it or not. It could also be different based on the OS(name/type)?

`actualFontSize`

On input, a pointer to a `floating-point` value. On return, this value contains the actual font size that was used to render the string.